# Does obeying the "law of the land" extend to extraterritorial jurisdiction?

Tags: fiqh, non-muslim-countries

Generally, Muslims are required to obey the "law of the land".

> Muslims are generally obliged to abide by the laws of the land and the country they live in... -- [DarulIftaa.com](http://daruliftaa.com/node/5852)

However, some countries enact [extraterritorial jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterritorial_jurisdiction), whereby offences are punishable in country X despite the offence taking place in country Y (and may even be legal in country Y).

**Question**: Does obeying the "law of the land" extend to extraterritorial jurisdiction?

To give an example of where this might arise, in Australia, the [Criminal Code](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2016C01150/) includes such laws:

> 272.8  Sexual intercourse with child outside Australia
>
> A person commits an offence if: (a)  the person engages in sexual intercourse with another person (the child); and (b)  the child is under 16; and (c)  the sexual intercourse is engaged in outside Australia.
>
> Penalty:  Imprisonment for 20 years.

It is possible that a Muslim Australian citizen is Islamically married to someone considered a child in Australia, and currently in a country which legally recognizes the marriage.  In this setting, it may be legal for that person to have sex with their spouse in a particular country, but is nevertheless punishable under Australian law.